# How to prevent forced line break between vbox and text when vbox starts a line and precedes text?

Tags: boxes

I was surprised to copy a character (I'd spent so much time to trim whitespace around) from a `\vbox` just to discover that it forces a line break whenever it precedes text (on the same line). Below is a simplified version that creates the same outcome. I need `@` to appear on the same line as `hello world`, without enclosing both within an `\hbox` (this is the only way I discovered that works, but I can't enclose `hello world`--only `@`--in my original code due to design issues).

P.S. let's limit solution to plain TeX code compiled in XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
  \newbox\zT
  \setbox\zT\vbox{\makeatletter@\makeatother}
  \copy\zT hello world\par % try 1 (failed)
  \hbox{\copy\zT}hello world % try 2 (failed)
\end{document}
```

[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT (APPROXIMATION):

[image]

Comment: Why not `\makeatletter\newcommand*\letterat{@}\makeatother` and then use `\letterat` instead of a box?

Comment: `\setbox\zT\hbox{\makeatletter@\makeatother}` .... `vbox` will take the whole linewidth ...

Comment: It would be ***much*** better if you explain what your ***real*** problem is.

Comment: \makeatletter@\makeatother ??? is the same as @

Comment: also note that latex does not include plain so you can not have "plain tex code compiled with xelatex" (there is only one command you use there that has the same name as a command defined in plain, `\newbox` but the version in latex is quite different (especially the version in xelatex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. let's limit solution to plain TeX code compiled in XeLaTeX.

there were no commands used in your example that are as defined in plain TeX, plain TeX has a `\newbox` command but with quite  different definition, and none of the other commands are commands defined in plain, they are either LaTeX commands or TeX primitives.

You have not said what you are trying to do, but LaTeX box commands are designed to avoid issues like this (and using tex primitive `\setbox` after you have loaded color is particularly dangerous, you can easily generate invalid PDF output with no warning)

The LaTeX markup would be

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
  \newsavebox\zT
  \sbox\zT{@}

  \usebox{\zT} hello world
\end{document}
```

[image]

To see what is wrong with your original note that a box does not start a paragraph, so in either of

```
\vbox{...}
Hello World
```

or

```
\hbox{...}
Hello World
```

The paragraph starts at `H` with the box contents coming before (that is, above) the paragraph.

Normally the solution is to use `\leavevmode` before the box to start the paragraph so `\leavevmode\hbox{@}` or better `\mbox{@}` or with a box register, `\leavevmode\copy\zT` or better `\usebox{\zT}`.

But in your case the box would not fit to the left of the `H` anyway as you have

```
\vbox{@}
```

so that is starting a paragraph inside vmode, so the paragraph text (`\indent` box, `@` and `\parfillskip`) will be wrapped to lines of width `\hsize` so the vbox contents include an `\hbox` of width `\hsize` (which is `\textwidth`) not just an `@`.

TeX can show you the box constructed by `\vbox{@}` :

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\setbox\zT\vbox{@}
\showbox\zT
\end{document}
```

produces

```
\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0
.\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 337.2222fil
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 @
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

so the vbox contains an hbox of width `\hsize` containing a zero sized empty hbox (for paragraph indent), the @ character and `\parfillskip` and `\rightskip` glue nodes.

Comment: @bp2017 you will break latex by using unsupported commands. And just because the texbook has a command of the same name doesn't mean that the latex command of that name is the same. As I comment in the answer `\newbox` is quite different.

Comment: @bp2017 I honestly can not understand what line of reasoning would say that you can not use `\sbox` because it is strictly latex but you can use `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` ????

Comment: @bp2017 the same applies to `\documentclass` and `\begin` they are defined in the same file, `latex.ltx` as `\sbox` based on the same tex primitives, there is absolutely no difference. and how does texbook describing `\newbox` defined as `\newbox=\outer macro: ->\alloc@ 4\box \chardef \insc@unt`  help understand a latex command of that name defined as `\newbox=macro: ->\e@alloc \box {\ifnum \allocationnumber <\@cclvi \expandafter \chardef \else \expandafter \e@alloc@chardef \fi } {\count 14}\insc@unt \float@count ` ?

Comment: @bp2017 no if you knew how "things work" you would never do `\setbox\zT\hbox{...}` after loading color, latex goes to great lengths never to do that or only to do it in very restricted contexts known to be safe, you would do `\setbox\zT\hbox{{...}}` with doubled brace group (which is what all latex box commands do. LaTeX simply is not designed to take arbitrary tex primitives mid document.

Comment: I tried in the answer above to say why the primitives did not work, I relegated the color issue to comments as it wasn't the main point of the question. But the basic premise that plain tex documentation gives code that is directly usable in latex is simply wrong. It is good to read that documentation and it does give a better understanding of how to code for latex, but the documentation is not directly applicable and if you insist on phrasing your questions with a latex example but a requirement for a plain tex answer there is never going to be a good answer possible.

Comment: @bp2017  no it's more like writing java code and expecting it to work in C. If you stick to simple expressions like  x=1+2 you might get lucky and it works, but in general you are doomed. You can of course make a new framework based on plain tex, but you can not expect that framework to work in latex (or at least not if you build it by reference only to the plain tex documentation, and not latex documentation)

Comment: @bp2017 no problem, just ask a new question with the question you actually wanted to ask:-)

Comment: @bp2017 you should ask a new question, discussing code in comment fomatting is useless. But you need `\leavevmode` before the `copy` as I describe in this answer, then the box comes to the left of hello word not above it, it is however all below the baseline as you constructed a vtop starting with a zero kern so that puts the reference point at its top edge.

Comment: @bp2017 or perhaps you want it below the baseline? as the same is true of the fbox version.  By the way I added `\documentclass{article}` to the top of your pastebin so it worked at all

Comment: @bp2017 I don't suppose you want me to mention that latex arranges that every box command, \mbox, \fbox, \makebox, \usebox, \includegraphics, ... all have definitions that begin with `\leavevmode` :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because a `\vbox` always automatically has width `\hsize` which is the width of the whole text block.  You could do something like `\vbox{\hsize=1em...}` but that's just nonsense since there are better solutions.

I have three proposals for you.

1. Define a macro inside `\makeatletter...other`.  This will freeze the catcode of `@` inside the macro, so using the macro to typeset `@` will not be affected by surrounding catcodes.

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand*\letterat{@}
   \makeatother
   ```
2. Define a character constant.  This will insert the character at the code that you provide.  Catcodes don't apply to a character constant.  The downside is that this costs one register, but with e-TeX nowadays that's not actually an issue.

   ```
   \chardef\letterat=`\@
   ```
3. Put the character in a hbox.  This has a couple of downside.  First the character does not adapt to the surrounding font at all, second it also costs a register and third it can't be placed in the preamble because fonts have to be loaded at the time you assign the box.

   ```
   \newbox\atbox
   \setbox\atbox=\hbox{@}
   \newcommand*\letterat{\leavevmode\unhcopy\atbox}
   ```

Comment: There's ***no*** reason for using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in this context. If we type `@`, TeX will happily print it.

Comment: @egreg I don't know the exact use-case.  OP said it doesn't work to type `@` but you're right that the MWE is not reflecting that.

Comment: better to say "automatically has the width of its contents" rather than "automatically has width \hsize"  `\vbox{@}` is `\hsize` wide but `\vbox{\hbox{@}}` is the width of `@` as in the first case it contains a \hbox of width \hsize, but in the second the \hbox is the width of @

Comment: +1 for `\leavevmode`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use plain TeX, don't embed things in LaTeX.

From your post I *guess* you have a character you want to trim the white space around. For instance, take `\times`.

This is the character with no white space around it, the hairline box around is just to show the bounding box.

[image]

If you want to use the clipped character, you can set it into a box and then `\copy` the box, but ***remember*** that a `\copy` command does not change from vertical to horizontal mode.

```
\newbox\btimesbox
% remove the white space on the left and on the right
\setbox\btimesbox=\hbox{\kern-0.35ex$\times$\kern-0.35ex}
% remove the white space at the bottom
\setbox\btimesbox=\hbox{\raise-0.03ex\box\btimesbox}
% we want the depth to be zero
\dp\btimesbox=0pt
% remove the white space at the top
\ht\btimesbox=1.1ex

\def\btimes{\leavevmode\copy\btimesbox}

\btimes\ hello world

t\btimes t

t$\times$t

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 I can't read your mind.